# ImageResizer S3Reader2 - 404 Error only when query parameters are provided

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer v3.4.3 with S3Reader2 plugin in ASP.NET MVC5 Project (5.2.3, .net 4.5)

Everything works fine with local images, and S3 hosted images if I provide no query string.

```
http://localhost/local-img-folder/filename.jpg?width=100
http://localhost/s3/bucket-name/folder/filename.jpg
```

If I'm trying to get the following url I get 404 error :

```
http://localhost/s3/bucket-name/folder/filename.jpg?width=100
```

This is my resizer Web.Config section

```
  <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="S3Reader2" prefix="~/s3" region="eu-west-1" buckets="XXXXXXXXXXX" accessKeyId="XXXXXXXXXXXX" secretAccessKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

By using Fiddler I've noticed that when I'm trying to pull S3 images with query parameters IIS is not even trying to reach out to AWS and the following error can be found in ELMAH log:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): No image exists at C:\DEV\GitHub\<projectpath>\s3\bucket-name\folder\filename.jpg
   at ImageProcessor.Web.Services.LocalFileImageService.<GetImage>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Why does adding a query parameter causes Resizer to use LocalFileImageService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageProcessor.Web.Services.LocalFileImageService` is not part of [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net), it's part of [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/).

You have both image servers installed and the latter is taking over the request and causing the failure.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I was so focused on Resizer configuration that I didn't even notice that this one is coming from a completely different library. Thank you!